# Django encoding error (ValueError) while template rendering

Tags: python, django

I am used Python 3.4 with Django 1.7.
When I override the error messages from NON_FIELD_ERRORS raised by model validation ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#considerations-regarding-model-s-error-messages)), I had ValueError:

`unsupported format character '?' (0x43d) …`

My form is:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS
from centre.settlers.models import FamilyList

class FamilyAdd(forms.ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    error_css_class = 'error'

    family = forms.CharField(max_length=80,label="Назва сім'ї")
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=255,required=False,label="Опис сім'ї",widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = FamilyList
        exclude = ['uid']
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': '%(field_labels) не є унікальними.'
            }
        }
```

`0x43d` is small Cyrillic letter 'н', the first letter after `(field_labels)`.

What is wrong? I use Python 3, it familiar with Unicode strings, my `forms.py` and template saved with UTF-8 codepage.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the format character `s` after the variable name:

```
'%(field_labels)s не є унікальними.'
```